How to fix '****found with a symbol with attributes' when converting R list to Python list while using rpy2 in RStudio?
I am attempting to convert an R list that consists of strings into the equivalent list in Python. I am using RStudio (version 4.3.1) and rpy2 to do this conversion. The version of Python I have is 3.12.0. The following code I first tried is:
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

r_list = robjects.r('r_list')
python_list = list(r_list)

Whenever I use this code I get the following message in the console:
****found symbol with attributes

And this message fills my console, eventually causing RStudio to freeze and crash.
Apparently this means that the list is not being converted because the list has attributes. I was told by chat GPT to remove the attributes of the list by using:
 attributes(r_list) <- NULL

But this didn't work, and I still got the same message. I observed that when I used
 attributes(r_list)

The console already showed NULL as an output. I also tried using
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

r_list = robjects.r('album_list')


r_list_no_attributes = robjects.baseenv['unclass'](r_list)

python_list = list(r_list_no_attributes)

print(python_list)

And this didn't work either. I feel like I have tried just about everything to solve this problem.
Here is a minimal reproducible example:
 h <- head(album_list)

h is
[1] "The Collective"   "Eternal Sunshine" "Visions"          
"Bleachers"        "Rebirth"         
[6] "Run Fast" 

If I then use the same code as shown before:
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

r_list = robjects.r('h')
python_list = list(r_list)

print(python_list)

I get this:
RStudio console prints out '****found symbol with attributes'
Then of course, RStudio as a whole freezes and crashes.

Please provide a [mre]. Specifically, show us original R object you are trying to convert. r_list or album_list? Right now, your code is not runnable for us.

@Parfait album_list has over 21,000 elements in it, so I won't be able to put it in a minimal reproducible example. I will take a portion of album_list which will be the first six elements, and put it into a list, and then turn that into the minimal reproducible example.

Yes, we only need a sample. Use dput to copy/paste object here. See How to make a great R reproducible example?

Please post the str() of your object. It looks to be an atomic character vector and not a list. Also, check the object r_list on Python side with type().

BTW - Did you take the time to research how to convert an R list/vector to Python list in rpy2? There are many web search hits and SO duplicates to your post. Please test such solutions.

@Parfait I did, and it's true that there are many questions asking how to convert an R list/vector to Python list in rpy2, but I couldn't find any that had the same error on SO: ****found symbol with attributes.' I did find one post on Github about a person who had the same error that I had, but it wasn't fixed, and it was only suggested that it's because rpy2 is not supported well on Windows.

I can reproduce this error by simply importing rpy2:
import rpy2.robjects as ro
This line crashes my rstudio with that dumb message.  I have versions as follows:
R - 4.3.3
reticulate - 1.36.0
RStudio - 2023.12.1 Build 402
Python - 3.12.2
rpy2 - 3.5.16
Surely someone must have an answer to this disaster?

This is the only example I've founded that even discusses the error:
https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/issues/942
The issue is never fixed, but it's suggested that Windows is the issue.

What happens outside RStudio? Specifically, open a Python shell at command line and run the import call.
